Finding broken references in Azure FHIR
Azure FHIR Service does not enforce referential integrity. I would like to query all resources that have broken links.
E.g. a MedicationDispense references a non-existing patient:
"resource": {
   "resourceType": "MedicationDispense",
   "id": "5d3c2805cb6a01d06982c955c344548839b0a80a",
   "subject": {
      "reference": "Patient/231fcf59d1872005d7943e85e3ceaea05d3765c1"
   }
}

However, in the FHIR service no Patient resource with id 231fcf59d1872005d7943e85e3ceaea05d3765c1 exists.
How would I query the MedicationDispense above?

as you found out (the hard way ? :) ) ....ms fhir server is a "dumb" data layer.. as in .. if you push data to it, it will store it.. even if ref integrity isn't legit.     while I have coded a custom-search-parameter for a piece of data that actually exists ... (patient--favorite-color as a silly example)..... it would be interesting to see if you  could write a "and where NOT exists" .. anyway.. not sure if anything would work..but maybe a breadcrumb to something interesting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/azure-api-for-fhir/how-to-do-custom-search

I also tried a search parameter, but to no avail. I ended up preprocessing the data in Spark (Azure Synapse) to annotate it before importing it to the FHIR service.

You could try MedicationDispense?patient._id:missing=true.  How that'll behave on Azure, I can't say though.

Thanks for the response. Doesn't seem to work on Azure, though. I receive an 'unknown error' with that modifier.
